# When do I need to re-install instead of upgrading?

Tags: system-installation, lts

Actually i need to know if i'm using 14.04 or 15.04 then do i'll need to a fresh installation of os after several time 5 yrs or 9 months?

Comment: - Your title and body do not match. - The title question is a matter of opinion so off-topic.

Comment: Whichever you choose, back up your user data first. Upgrades are usually trouble-free, but not always.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the release you are using is an active one (so did not go end of life) you have the option to upgrade or to re-install. A re-install can be done without removing your personal documents.

A [list of dates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) when Ubuntu versions go end of life is available on our wiki.

In October 15.10 arrives. If using 15.04 you have until January 2016 to upgrade to 15.10. Or you can always opt to re-install at that time.

If using 14.04 (LTS) you have until 2019 to upgrade to another release but  3 years before it goes EOL 16.04 will arrive so that would be the next upgrade version when you want to move across LTS releases.

As always and it should be common sense anyways: backups will save you time and hassle when upgrading, re-installing or when doing anything drastic to your system.

Comment: Anything drastic? o_O =)

Comment: yeah like someone telling the system to format a partition ;)

Comment: a @terdon maybe? =)

Comment: @A.B.: installing a custom kernel because you bought a new piece of hardware that isn't supported by your current kernel is a *great* example of **doing something drastic!  ;-)**